# Quantifying bit security for smart-vercauteren encryption scheme

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, security-definition

I am working on project that requires to compare in terms of security between two encryption schemes, one of them is the SV scheme.  However, I dont know what are the steps exactly towards quantifying bit security. Below is what I really got from reading multiple papers, I really hope I can get some directions :

SV is built on top of Gentrys FHE in ideal lattices, its is based on small principle ideal problem ( that is currently solved in polynomisl time) it also provides semantic security based on polynomial coset problem. There is a security parameter that is related to a security key yet I dont know its correspondance to typical encryption key sizes

Comment: I beg your pardon, but I didn't understand your last sentence...

Comment: @Vitor I meant bit security and how it is going to be mapped to RSA bit security